# Loading video when clicking forward or Backward video in MPMoviePlayerController-iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

It will showing black screen with loading activity indicator When i click the video in full screen and touch up the forward or Backward button.

I have using the following code for movie player

```
    NSURL *fURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.winnersCircleDictionary objectForKey:@"videoname"]];


self.players=nil;

self.players=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:fURL];

[self.players setContentURL:fURL];

self.players.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

self.players.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

[[self.players view] setFrame:_webviewWinnerCircle.frame];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.players];

                                          object:nil];

self.players.shouldAutoplay=NO;

self.players.currentPlaybackTime=0.0;

[scrollViewWinnerCircle addSubview:self.players.view];
```

Forward and Backward button working fine in iOS 6 and this issue only have in iOS 7. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and got the issue , And solved like this.
Prepared the `MoviePlayer` like `[self.players prepareToPlay];`  for playing the selected video after adding the self.player.view as subview to the `scrollViewWinnerCircle`.

The code is as follows.

```
self.players = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:fURL];      
[self.players setContentURL:fURL];
self.players.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
self.players.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[[self.players view] setFrame:_containerView.frame];
self.players.shouldAutoplay = NO;
self.players.currentPlaybackTime = 0.0;

[_containerView addSubview:self.players.view];
[self.players prepareToPlay];   // Prepares a movie player for playback.
[self.players pause];           // Pause playback of the loaded movie
```

Comment: Sorry buddy! i try above code in iOS 7 but now also same issue occurred when i click the video in full screen using MPMoviePlayerController and touch up the forward or backward button.

Comment: can i see you code inside moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged notification selector method ?

Comment: -(void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(MPMoviePlayerController *)player
{
   if (self.players.playbackState==MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
    {
}
}

Comment: It may be the problem with the url you supplied for the resource file. I just tried with a sample app loading video from the resource bundle like NSURL *fURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]; , And it is working for me correctly

Comment: http://demo.rifluxyss.com/T3/saratoga/images/winnervideos/winner.MOV    Please try this URL.

Comment: I have using above URL for playing video.This issue may be due to URL problem.Please check above URL and please guide me if you have found any solution.Thank you show much for your effort for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with the source, also didn't specified the source type.
Do like the following, its working for me with the url i used here.

```
    NSURL *fURL      = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

    self.players = nil;
    self.players = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:fURL];
    [self.players setContentURL:fURL];

// Specifying media source type
    self.players.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

It take some time to load initially.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this code instead of MPMovieplayerController and import these library in you class: 
AVKit
AVFoundation

NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];

playerViewController.player = player;

[player play];

[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

after using above code you will be able to forward and back forward video.